# How to apply simple functions on sequentially labelled variables in a data frame?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to apply series of simple functions on many variables labelled sequentially AND bind these newly created variables to the same data frame. I managed to do the first part (largely with the help of a previous answer) but not the second part.

```
dat <- data.frame(x1=sample(c(0:1)), av1 = sample(10) , av2 = sample(10) , av3 = sample(10),av4=sample(10))
dat$t1<-ifelse(dat$x1==1,dat$av1*2/7,dat$av1*5/7)
dat$t2<-ifelse(dat$x1==1,dat$av2*2/7,dat$av2*5/7)
dat$t3<-ifelse(dat$x1==1,dat$av3*2/7,dat$av3*5/7)
dat$t4<-ifelse(dat$x1==1,dat$av4*2/7,dat$av4*5/7)
dat
```

Basically, I would like to repeat these ifelse statement over all values of av1,av2,av3.. to create corresponding variables labelled as tu1, tu2, tu3 without re-typing function each time. For example:

```
dat <- cbind(dat,  sapply(dat[grep("av", names(dat))], function(col) { ifelse(dat$x1==0, col*2/7, col*5/7) } ) )
```

However, now all the new variables are also labelled as av. I guess I can change the names of columns afterwards, e.g.:

```
names( dat)[10:13] <- gsub("av", "tu", names(dat)[10:13])
```

Because I keep adding/removing variables beforehand in my code those column numbers keep changing.  Is there a way for me to create, attach and relabel new variables simultaneously?  Or is there a better way of applying the same function over sequentially labelled variables?

Comment: Instead of listing column numbers, you can use `duplicated(colnames(dat))` right after executing the `sapply` to rename these columns using `gsub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
out <- ifelse(matrix(dat$x1,nrow(dat),sum(grepl("av",colnames(dat)))) == 1,
              as.matrix(dat[,grepl("av",colnames(dat))]) * 2 / 7,
              as.matrix(dat[,grepl("av",colnames(dat))]) * 5 / 7)

colnames(out) <- paste0("tu",seq_len(ncol(out)))
```

That's a bit more compact than it needs to be, since I'm doing all the coercion in one go. It might be clearer to extract the piece of `dat` that you need, and create the indicator matrix separately.

Another option would be to `melt` your data frame and operate on it by groups and then recast it to wide format.